# SQL - extracting all pairs only once

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Problem statement:

- a table with N columns, K out of which are used in a criterion to determine pairs of rows
- such a criterion involving the K columns can simply be if columns c_1, c2, .. c_k are equal for the two different rows part of a pair (the criterion itself is not relevant, only the fact that it must be used)
- the requirement is to extract all potential pairs, but only once. This means that if for a row there are more than 2 potential other rows that can form a pair given the above criterion, then only one pair must be extracted

Simple example:

Input table:

```
A | B | C
x | y | z
w | y | z
u | y | z
u | v | z
v | v | z
```

Criterion: B and C columns must be the same for two rows to be part of a pair.

Output:

```
x | y | z
w | y | z
u | v | z
v | v | z
```

What hints do you have for solving the problem in pure SQL (or in the Oracle dialect, if specific features help)?

Comment: Hint: self-join

Comment: @Psi self-join requires two table scans - analytic functions would only require one.

Comment: If the criteria is that `B` and `C` are equal to be a pair and only one of a pair should be extracted then why do you have multiple rows for `y / z` and `v / z`?

Comment: `...row_number() over(partition by B,C order by A) as rn  .. rn<=2`

Comment: @MT0: that is the main issue. The input table does not have an even amount of rows that are part of a pair. Otherwise the solution would have a bit more trivial. The required solution can involve any choice of row pairs as long as it does not provide the set of all possible pairs and produces exactly _M_ pairs given that there are _2M+1_ rows that satisfy the criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use window analytic function:

```
CREATE TABLE TT1 (A VARCHAR(4), B VARCHAR(4), C VARCHAR(4))
INSERT INTO TT1 VALUES ('x','y','z')
INSERT INTO TT1 VALUES ('w','y','z')
INSERT INTO TT1 VALUES ('u','y','z')
INSERT INTO TT1 VALUES ('u','v','z')
INSERT INTO TT1 VALUES ('v','v','z')
INSERT INTO TT1 VALUES ('k','w','z')


SELECT A.A, A.B, A.C 
FROM
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B,C ORDER BY A DESC) RN, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY B,C ) RC
FROM TT1) A
WHERE A.RN <=2 AND RC>1
```

Output:

```
A    B    C
---- ---- ----
v    v    z
u    v    z
x    y    z
w    y    z
```

Comment: Probably RN <= 2*(RC/2)

Comment: @Serg maybe I am missing something, but the _RN <= 2*(RC/2) _ condition does not work with the simple example.

Comment: Try 2*FLOOR(RC/2)

Comment: @Serg: indeed, one needs to alter the where clause as you suggested to account for the presence of more than one pair meeting the criterion.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `COUNT()` analytic function partitioning on those rows you want to match as pairs:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(*) OVER (
             PARTITION BY B, C
             ORDER BY A
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
         ) AS current_rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (
             PARTITION BY B, C
             ORDER BY A
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING
         ) AS next_rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  MOD( current_rn, 2 ) = 0
OR     MOD( next_rn, 2 ) = 0;
```

**Output**:

```
A B C
- - -
u y z
w y z
u v z
v v z
```

Comment: ..COUNT(DISTINCT A)  OVER ( PARTITION BY B, C) AS cnt.. cnt>1 and rn<=2

Comment: equally valid solution. Thank you - interesting variation using the `ROWS BETWEEN..` construct.